# What are roles of package managers and preprocessor in build system of Gulp?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

What are roles of package managers and preprocessors in build system of GulpJS?

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow as its too broad - "Please Search, and research" and take a good look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you read so far? What specifically don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package managers

Package Manager Bower and Using Gulp to Manage Components

Install Bower
$ npm install -g bower

Finding Packages
$ bower search 
Ex: $ bower search jquery

Installing a Package
$ bower install  --save
Ex: $ bower install jquery --save

Updating Packages
$ bower update

More: http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components

Answer (score 0):

A Build System is refered to as collection of tasks(collectively called as task runners), which automate the repetitive work.These tasks may be like Compilation of preprocess CSS and JavaScript, Minification of files to reduce its size, Concatenation of files into one and Triggering the

The build system works with 3 components Package managers(bower, npm), Preprocessors and Task runners(gulp and grunt).